# Pivotting on oracle v10.2.0 with two dynamic values

Tags: oracle, plsql, pivot, oracle10g, dynamic-pivot

I need to get a query result like this:

```
        |Person1                  |Person2                  |Person3                  |...
        ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Date1   |function(Person1Id,Date1)|function(Person2Id,Date1)|function(Person3Id,Date1)|...         
Date2   |function(Person1Id,Date2)|function(Person2Id,Date2)|function(Person3Id,Date2)|...
Date3   |function(Person1Id,Date3)|function(Person2Id,Date3)|function(Person3Id,Date3)|...
.
.
.
```

Dates are coming from the user and PersonIds are coming from a table. What I need to is just sending ids and dates o the function and get the result of it. Since I am working on oracle v10.2.0 pivoting does not work and writing case...when statements for each person will not work because there are lots of people in the table I am fetching.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Conditional Aggregation within DB version `10g` such as

```
SELECT myDate,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PersonId=1 THEN myfunc(PersonId,myDate) END) AS Person1,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PersonId=2 THEN myfunc(PersonId,myDate) END) AS Person2,
       MAX(CASE WHEN PersonId=3 THEN myfunc(PersonId,myDate) END) AS Person3
  FROM t 
 GROUP BY myDate
```

**Update :** Yet, there exists an option, even in DB `10g` for dynamic pivoting by using `SYS_REFCURSOR`, eg. using PL/SQL rather than using SQL only, and show the result set on the command line if you're using SQL Developer. Create a stored function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_person_rs RETURN SYS_REFCURSOR IS
  v_recordset SYS_REFCURSOR;
  v_sql       VARCHAR2(32767);
  v_str       VARCHAR2(32767);
BEGIN
  WITH tt AS
  ( 
   SELECT PersonId, 
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY PersonId) AS rn  
     FROM t 
    GROUP BY PersonId 
  )
  SELECT TO_CHAR(RTRIM(XMLAGG(XMLELEMENT(e, 
           'MAX(CASE WHEN PersonId = '||PersonId||
                   ' THEN myfunc(PersonId,myDate) 
                      END) AS Person'||rn         
           , ',')).EXTRACT('//text()').GETCLOBVAL(), ','))
    INTO v_str         
    FROM tt;  

  v_sql :=
  'SELECT myDate, '|| v_str ||'
     FROM t
    GROUP BY myDate';

  OPEN v_recordset FOR v_sql;
  RETURN v_recordset;
END;
```

in which, `ROW_NUMBER()` Analytic function, which is available in `10g`, is used, but `LISTAGG()` string aggregation function is not yet in `10g`. So `XMLAGG` is used instead. This generated SQL string within the function is also exactly same as the above one, eg. in Conditionally Aggregated Logic.

Then run the below code :

```
VAR rc REFCURSOR
EXEC :rc := get_person_rs;
PRINT rc
```

from SQL Developer's Command Line in order to see the expected result set dynamically generated by currently existing data.

Comment: Barbaros, thank you so much for your time and help. However, the number of the person will be like more than 300, in this case, I will be writing case when for every person, right? If yes, I need to write dynamically for each person, do you know any solution for that?

Comment: you're welcome brother. it's not possible through sql, but might be with PL/SQL, indeed you originally tagged `plsql`, through use of `dynamic queries`, but still seems like a daunting issue :) @ilhank .

Comment: Besides `two dimensional arrays` would be used with PL/SQL Code @ilhank .

Comment: Thank you so much Barbaros, I will go with dynamic queries first. Let's see what will happen.